# Pass Javascript variable to PHP on as image

Tags: javascript, php, image

I found a cool github  project for webpage signatures here https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad.

The example code saves the signature as an image and downloads it, code below. I need to instead pass the image back to my php script so I can save it on the server. Any help would be appreciated.

```
savePNGButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
    alert("Please provide a signature first.");
  } else {
    var dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL();
    download(dataURL, "signature.png");
  }
});
```

Comment: Ajax POST call and pass the dataURL to the server.

Answer (score 0):

For what i can see, you can use

```
// JS Returns signature image as an array of point groups
var imgData = signaturePad.toData();
```

to store signature locally on a JS variable as base64 encoded and then send it to the server with AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php?action=saveSomeImage",
    data: {img: encodeURIComponent(imgData)},
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    success: function(){
        //...
    }
});
```

Then, on on the PHP side write it to disk

```
file_put_contents('foo.png', base64_decode( urldecode($_POST['img'])));
```

Comment: OK thank you. I don't do much front end programming. So how do I make imgData variable part of a POST to my PHP script? I am sure it is simple but I do not know..

Comment: You just need to do a ajax POST

Comment: @ComputationSmomputation, added some code example for ajax

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to pass it in JSON to PHP. Something like this should do the job (I used jQuery):

```
savePNGButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
    alert("Please provide a signature first.");
  } else {
    var dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL();
    obj={};
    obj["signature"] = dataURL;

 var data=JSON.stringify(obj);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'yourphp.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(msg) {
//do something on success
            console.log(msg)

        },error: function(msg) {
//do something on error
            console.log(msg)
        }

  }
});
```